# How to Allocate RAM using Windows Subsystem For Linux(WSL) in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu-16.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have been exploring how to allocate RAM to WSL in windows 10.
please help me i have done 90% project setup but stuck with increasing RAM memory?

## i am getting below error while installing app server...

### Check Physical Memory Requirements

This system does not have sufficient memory installed to run XYZ.

XYZ requires at least 4GB of RAM installed.  This system reports 0.0GB of RAM
installed.

Aborting install.

Comment: i am getting below error while installing app server ===============================================================================
Check Physical Memory Requirements
----------------------------------

This system does not have sufficient memory installed to run XYZ.

XYZ requires at least 4GB of RAM installed.  This system reports 0.0GB of RAM
installed.

Aborting install.